# Iterate a script over multiple folders in master folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I have written a script that extracts columns from multiple csv files (staying in a folder named SIM1) and saves them in a txt file. Now, I need to iterate this script over multiple folders (SIM2, SIM3, SIM4,...). All of these SIM folders are in one master folder. I will really appreciate if I can get help on iteration? (I am using Python 3.7)

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import csv

    os.chdir(r'D:\GRIDS\SIM1')

    ppt = pd.read_csv("ppt.csv")
    et = pd.read_csv("et.csv")
    tmx = pd.read_csv("tmax.csv")
    weather_SIM = pd.read_csv("Weather_SIM1.csv")

    big_frame = pd.concat([weather_SIM, ppt,et,tmx], axis=1)

    np.savetxt('Weather.txt', big_frame, fmt= "%0.0f\t %0.0f\t %0.0f\t %0.1f\t %0.1f\t %0.1f", header='Year\t Month\t Date\t ppt\t et\t tmax', comments='')
```

Comment: Prepend a path instead of chdiring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

master_path = '<master dir path>'
subfolders = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(master_path, x)), os.listdir(master_path)))
for folder in subfolders:

    ppt = pd.read_csv(f"{master_path}/{folder}/ppt.csv")
    et = pd.read_csv(f"{master_path}/{folder}/et.csv")
    tmx = pd.read_csv(f"{master_path}/{folder}/tmax.csv")
    weather_SIM = pd.read_csv(f"{master_path}/{folder}/Weather_SIM1.csv")

    big_frame = pd.concat([weather_SIM, ppt,et,tmx], axis=1)

    np.savetxt(f"{master_path}/{folder}/Weather.txt", big_frame, fmt= "%0.0f\t %0.0f\t %0.0f\t %0.1f\t %0.1f\t %0.1f", header='Year\t Month\t Date\t ppt\t et\t tmax', comments='')
```

Comment: Hey Rajith, Thanks for the help. This code works perfectly fine.

Comment: great,happy coding